# jQuery Masonry Plugin - Rendering Elements Outside Parent Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-scroll, masonry

I've made a few changes on my website lately, since then Masonry jQuery plugin sometimes renders elements (using infinite scroll) outside of the parent container - 
100% of the time on its right side:

[image: element rendered outside parent container]

I have absolutely no idea whats causing it neither any idea on how to debug.
It's a big issue since when you continue scrolling, the outside'd element is returned to the container - causing **existing elements to reposition** after they already rendered, making the website really hard to use.

You can watch the problem here:
http://il.memofish.com/dashboard

I've made a video describing the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcWhSRQiD68

Thank you.

Comment: I am not experiencing the issue you are describing in Chrome. Hopefully that's some kind of hint.

Comment: Sorry, also not experiencing it.

Comment: @Antiga , I'm on chrome. On every infinite scroll function call, scroll up and look on the right side of the page - you'll see the problematic element in about 3-4 scrolls.

Comment: @GalWeissman I refreshed 3 different times and scrolled the entire way until I ran out of content. I kept scrolling up and looking for it, but I have yet to see it. I'm on Chrome 39 (dev channel). I'm not sure if that's helping something, but have you tried reproducing this in Incognito mode so that you could eliminate plugins as a possibility?

Comment: @Antiga - I've made a video describing the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcWhSRQiD68

Comment: @GalWeissman I watched it and tried doing exactly what you were doing. I tried several times. I can't reproduce that. Did you see what I said about possible interference with plugins/extensions? (On an off-topic note, I love the design with the loader circle around the fish.)

Comment: @Antiga Yes, it happens to me also @ incognito mode. Chrome @ Mac Version 37.0.2062.94

Comment: @Antiga - offtopic: thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it:
The website has different masonry bricks width, that what caused the problem.
I gave masonry the option of 'column-width:1', meaning the calculation of the bricks' sizes will be dynamic via DOM elements rendering.
Worked like a charm.